# R: I want to create a dummy that goes to 1 after a particular date

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, survey, dummy-variable

I have a survey dataset that looks like this. The "Year", "Month" and "Date" columns capture the date the interview was carried out, and the data goes until December 30th 2018:

```
| Year | Month | Date | USDollar |Governate|
|------|-------|------|----------|---------|
| 2018 |   6   |  10  |  38.50   |    11   |
| 2018 |   6   |  12  |  38.52   |    12   |
| 2018 |   6   |  14  |  38.61   |    10   |
| 2018 |   6   |  18  |  38.63   |    12   |
| 2018 |   6   |  21  |  38.63   |    13   |
| 2018 |   7   |  22  |  38.65   |    12   |
| 2018 |   7   |  23  |  39.41   |    13   |
| 2018 |   7   |  24  |  39.42   |    15   |
| 2018 |   7   |  02  |  39.43   |    12   |
| 2018 |   7   |  03  |  39.50   |    13   |
```

And so on. What I want to do is to create a dummy variable that is 1 if the date is after October 7th, and 0 if the date is before October 7th. I want to call this variable "post_float".

I tried using this command `df$post_float <- ifelse(df$month >= 10 & df$date >= 7, 1, 0)` but that didn't quite do it. It's okay for the most part but it messes up some of the dates (like, for instance, November 5th since that doesn't match the command requirements). How can I set up the dummy such that it goes to 1 on October 7th and stays that way until the end of the dataset?

Thanks for the help, and sorry if I'm missing anything obvious, I'm new to R.

Comment: Where does your dataset end does it cover many years?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#Data

Data <- structure(list(Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), Month = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), Date = c(10L, 12L, 14L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 2L, 3L), USDollar = c(38.5, 38.52, 38.61, 38.63, 38.63, 
38.65, 39.41, 39.42, 39.43, 39.5), Governate = c(11L, 12L, 10L, 
12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 12L, 13L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

#Date
Data$FormatedDate <- as.Date(paste0(Data$Year,'-',Data$Month,'-',Data$Date),'%Y-%m-%d') 
#Variable
Data$post_float <- ifelse(Data$FormatedDate>as.Date('2018-10-07'),1,0)

   Year Month Date USDollar Governate FormatedDate post_float
1  2018     6   10    38.50        11   2018-06-10          0
2  2018     6   12    38.52        12   2018-06-12          0
3  2018     6   14    38.61        10   2018-06-14          0
4  2018     6   18    38.63        12   2018-06-18          0
5  2018     6   21    38.63        13   2018-06-21          0
6  2018     7   22    38.65        12   2018-07-22          0
7  2018     7   23    39.41        13   2018-07-23          0
8  2018     7   24    39.42        15   2018-07-24          0
9  2018     7    2    39.43        12   2018-07-02          0
10 2018     7    3    39.50        13   2018-07-03          0
```

Answer (score 0):

The column structure of the date suggests the use of `ISOdate`.

```
d <- transform(d, 
               post_float=+(do.call("ISOdate", unname(d[1:3])) > 
                              ISOdate(2018, 10, 07)))
d
#    Year Month Date USDollar Governate post_float
# 1  2018     6   10    38.50        11          0
# 2  2018     6   12    38.52        12          0
# 3  2018     7   22    38.65        12          0
# 4  2018     7   23    39.41        13          0
# 5  2018     8   24    39.42        15          0
# 6  2018     9    2    39.43        12          0
# 7  2018    10    6    39.50        13          0
# 8  2018    10    7    39.50        13          0
# 9  2018    10    8    39.50        13          1
# 10 2018    10    9    39.50        13          1
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), Month = c(6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Date = c(10L, 12L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 2L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L), USDollar = c(38.5, 38.52, 38.65, 39.41, 39.42, 39.43, 
39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5), Governate = c(11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```